# How do I position the footer that responds appropriately to all browsers?

Tags: html, css, position, footer, absolute

My footer is not being positioned at the bottom of the page as it should. It is only responding to the updated browsers/hardware. I'm new to programming so I'm not probably not explaining this all too well. But I hope it makes sense. I can't show my code, it has issues I cant figure out.

you can view everything here using developer tools
[mindstyledecor.com](http://mindstyledecor.com/)

Comment: It looks like its working in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Comment: but it doesn't respond to mobile apps or older browser versions

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me also. One thing you could try is set

```
`footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
}`
```

which will ensure it sticks to the bottom of your page. You would also have to give a `height` to your `body` element.

Comment: I think the position is what is causing the problem. The footer itself is overlapping on top of the images I have uploaded. I would post it here to show the example but I'm not able to.